# Django CSRF Verifcation failed - Class based views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-csrf

I'm using class-based views.

```
class UserCreate(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data.get
        social_id = data('social_id')
        social_source = data('social_source')
        user = User(social_id=social_id, social_source=social_source, access_token=access_token)
        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({'response':200})
```

Whenever I post data on this URL, it says `CSRF token missing or incorrect.`

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
  \"social_id\": \"string\",
  \"social_source\": \"FB/Gmail\",
  \"access_token\": \"string\"
}" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/"
```

I've had this problem while getting data from the form in function views. There I used to add @csrf_exempt on my view and it would work. When I added @csrf_exempt to my `post` method, it does not work. How can I post the data?

Comment: For more information on class decoration, here is the link to the related django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because is class_based views you need to `decorate` the `dispatch method` for csrf_exempt to work

```
class UserCreate(View):
  @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(UserCreate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

  def post():
  ....
```

Comment: Thanx. This really helped me.

Comment: `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, method_decorator` then decorate the class with `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')`. This ought to prevent the need for defining a wrapper on the dispatch method.

Comment: For those who dont want the vulnerability, how do we avoid this error while using the class based architecture for models (like OP)-- any idea? I believe the post is abstracted through my use of `modelObject.objects.create(...)` within my class' `post` method. How should I make sure the token is used? It's in the request headers for sure, made available in the args as seen: `def post(self, request: HttpRequest) -> JsonResponse:` ...

Comment: Found the answer. The decorator to import is `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect` and just like before, decorate the class: `@method_decorator(csrf_protect, name='dispatch')`. Now it seems I am using the token in my post request and they are working.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply create the view from the CBV, and wrap it with the decorator like this:

`user_view = csrf_exempt(UserCreate.as_view())`

Complete example:

## views.py

```
class UserCreate(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data.get
        social_id = data('social_id')
        social_source = data('social_source')
        user = User(social_id=social_id, social_source=social_source, access_token=access_token)
        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({'response':200})

user_create = csrf_exempt(UserCreate.as_view())
```

## urls.py

```
from myapp.views import user_create

urlpatternts = [
    ...
    url(r'^pattern-here/$', user_create, name='user-create'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: I've added full example.

Answer (score 3):

`@csrf_exempt` is a decorator for functions, not Class Based Views. In order to get CSRF Exempt on a CBV install `django-braces` and import CsrfExemptMixin as follows:

`from braces.views import CsrfExemptMixin`

and implement it this way:

```
class UserCreate(CsrfExemptMixin, View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data.get
        social_id = data('social_id')
        social_source = data('social_source')
        user = User(social_id=social_id, social_source=social_source, access_token=access_token)
        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({'response':200})
```